# Does Funkload store cached data?

Tags: python, funkload

I want to make sure that I am not fetching the cached images while testing for performance results (so that it will not give me wrong interpretation).

```
class Simple(FunkLoadTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        # fetch urls from a file ... ending up with something like
        urlList = ['myurl']
        self.urlList = urlList

    def test_simple(self):
        for url in self.urlList:
            self.get(url, description='Get url')
```

Now `myurl` is a static page and all the images when accessed second time around, will be browser cached.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Refer to: http://funkload.nuxeo.org/README.html which mentions the following about Funk Load:

> It also simulates a browser cache by not reloading a css, a javascript or an image twice

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.